# How to print data found in Binary Search Tree?

Tags: c++, csv, binary-tree

I am doing this program which reads a CSV file and enters it in a tree, until now I have managed to create the tree and it shows them in order, however with the search I have a failure since it does not show the information of the element that is being searched , someone who can help me correct the fault, thanks....

The csv file contains the data(contains several but I leave these for example.):

1,name1,number1
2,name2,number2
3,name3,number3

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <experimental/optional>
intmax_t dato;

struct Person {
  intmax_t key;
  std::string name;
  intmax_t num;
};

struct Node : Person {
  Node(const Person &person) : Person(person) {}
  std::unique_ptr<Node> left, right;
  void insert(const Person &person);
};


void Node::insert(const Person &person) {
  /* recur down the tree */
  if (key > person.key) {
    if (left)
        left->insert(person);
    else
        left = std::make_unique<Node>(person);
  } else if (key < person.key) {
    if (right)
        right->insert(person);
    else
        right = std::make_unique<Node>(person);
  }
}

std::vector<Person> persons;

void inorder(Node *root) {
  if (root) {
    // cout<<"\t";

    inorder(root->left.get());
    std::cout <<  "\tID: "<< root->key << "\tName: "<< root->name << "\t\tNum: " << root->num << '\n'; //'\t' ' '
    inorder(root->right.get());
  }
}


std::experimental::optional<Person> busqueda(Node *root, intmax_t dato) {
    if(root==NULL){
    return {};
    }
    else if(root->key==dato){
        return *root;
    }
    else if(dato<root->key){
       return busqueda(root->left.get(),dato);
    }
    else{
        return busqueda(root->right.get(),dato);
    }
}



int main() {

  std::unique_ptr<Node> root;
  std::ifstream fin("data.txt");
  if (!fin) {
    std::cout << "File not open\n";
    return 1;
  }

  std::string line;
  const char delim = ',';
   std::cout<<"\t\tData\n"<<std::endl;
  while (std::getline(fin, line)) {
    std::istringstream ss(line);
    Person person;
    ss >> person.key;
    ss.ignore(10, delim);
    std::getline(ss, person.name, delim);
    ss >> person.num;
    if (ss) persons.push_back(person);
  }

  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < persons.size(); i++) {
    std::cout << std::setw(10)<<"ID:   " << persons[i].key << std::setw(30)<<"Name:   "
              << persons[i].name << std::setw(20) <<"Num:   "<< persons[i].num << '\n';
    if (!root) root = std::make_unique<Node>(persons[i]);
    else root->insert(persons[i]);
  }

  std::cout << "\n\n\t\tInorder:\n\n";

  inorder(root.get());



    std::cout<<" Enter data: "; std::cin>> dato;
        busqueda(root.get(),dato);
        if(busqueda(root.get(),dato)){
                std::cout<<"Data found"<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<root->name;//does not show the wanted, only the first of the document.
         }
        else{
            std::cout<<"\nData not found"<<std::endl;
        }

  return 0;
}
```

---

Comment: If it works, it asks me for the data, it even tells me if it was found, but when I want to show the found data, it always shows me the information of the first data of the document and not the one I was looking for.

Comment: Recommend a quick re-write of the question to clarify it. You can't count of people reading the comments for clarifications and you can't count on the comments not getting deleted

Comment: You throw away the result of your search. `busqueda(root.get(),dato);` returns an optional value `std::experimental::optional<Person>`  that you only test for its existence but don't use. I think you need `auto result = busqueda(root.get(),dato);` if (result)  { ... print the result instead of the root node.

Comment: For example I want to search for data 3, I want
print me key: 3 name: name3 and num number 3, but actually
if I put the 3 it shows me key: 1 name1 and number1, it is what I try to correct.

Comment: How could I implement it?

Comment: I tried it but it gives me error when showing result " error : no match for 'operator<<´

Comment: It should be `std::cout<<result.name;` You have not made an operator << for your Person struct,

Comment: |129|error: 'class std::experimental::fundamentals_v1::optional<Person>' has no member named 'name'|
||=== Build failed: 1 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 0 second(s)) ===|

Comment: I am sorry its `std::cout<<result->name;`

Answer (score 0):

From the comments you throw away the result of your search in the following statement:

`busqueda(root.get(),dato);` returns an optional value std::experimental::optional but you don't make use of the value.

You test the value with `if(busqueda(root.get(),dato)){` but since you did not store the result you both searched a second time and do not have a way to get the Person object.

Instead you can do this to get the person object and show its name:

```
std::cout << " Enter data: "; std::cin >> dato;
auto result = busqueda(root.get(), dato);
if (result) {
    std::cout << "Data found" << std::endl;
    std::cout <<result->name; // This should be the name of the found Person
}
else {
    std::cout << "\nData not found" << std::endl;
}
```